# Move Full Screen Apps to LEFT of Desktop on Mac OS X (Moutain Lion)

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I own a MacBook Pro running OS X Mountain Lion and enjoy the convenience and efficiency of being able to three finger (or four finger) swipe between full screen apps.

It irritates me however that full screen apps are only ever added to the right of the desktop and within "Mission control" whilst I'm able to change the order of full screen apps on the right I am NOT able to move/drag a full screen app to the LEFT of the desktop.

If I'm working predominantly on the desktop with two lesser used full screen apps, the most gesture efficient way of organizing your screens is to have one fullscreen app to the left of the desktop and one to the right, that seems obvious to me.

Anyone know of anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second desktop in Mission Control (top right corner) and use that one as your main desktop. While the first desktop is fixed to the left of all desktops and full-screen apps, any additional desktop can be reordered.

You might want to change keyboard shortcuts in *System Prefererences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts* as well.